# How to search using multiple products titles (Shopify) REST API?

Tags: php, shopify

Is it possible to search using several titles in one API call?

For example:

```
/admin/products.json?title=title1,title2&fields=id,title&limit=250
```

as you see  I added title1,title2  as I do in its search

This is that possible in Shopify? If not what is the best way to search if I have 500 product title and I want their id.

I'm using PHP, Curl to send these requests.

Answer (score 1):

You either search by exact title, or make your own title searching fuzzy logic. I do a simple callback to an App with a proxy using JS. The JS sends in a part of a title. I have all the titles of all the products in my DB. I use the fragment from JS to extract the match from the titles, and then return all the ID's that matched. Took about 30 minutes to roll all that out. You probably won't see fuzzy matching from Shopify, so roll your own.

Comment: I'm storing the titles  and handles for each product  but I thought it would be better to search by several titles at once. since each request might take 1 second.   but if they offer search like Id   where I can add many ids and get all products related to these ids  it will be much faster. your idea it not bad  but If  I have store with +10000 products it will be very slow

Comment: Whatever. You are obviously in for your long sessions of trial and error, so good luck to you! By the way, it has been since the early 1990's that full text search became fast enough so that the massive Internet was searchable fast, as per Google. 10000 products is a puny dataset, searchable in sub-second time.